# What is difference between swift protocol with and without class inheritance? and when to use class inherited and not inherited protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

I am not able to understand the difference between below code and what are the scenarios that we need to use this both protocol.

```
    protocol protocolName {} 
    protocol protocolName: class {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
protocol protocolName: class {}
```

can only be adopted by classes

[image]